# How to secure nodered with username and password

Tags: node-red

How can I add authentication for `nodered` console while running through docker?

docker-compose :

```
  node-red:
    container_name: nodered
    image: nodered/node-red
    ports:
      - "1880:1880"
    links:
      - redis
    volumes:
      - node_red_data:/node_modules      
    networks:
     - unifactNetwork
```

I tried to volume mount the `node_modules` directory inside the container and tried to run `node-red-admin hash-pw` inside the container and updated the `node-red-admin/settings.js` file with the new token. But that didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your volume mount won't work. `/node_modules` is not a directory used by anything.

As described in the README.md for the Node-RED container, the userDir is at `/data`. You will need to include a modified `settings.js` in a volume mounted to this directory.

Running `node-red-admin` in an already running container again won't work because the `/data/settings.js` file is read when Node-RED is started so editing after the start will not change what it running.